# Combine functions with selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select the parent element of the current element, then going to the next one and selecting the anchor tag inside that element. So for example, my DOM looks like this:

```
-td
  - span  (my element)
- td
- a
```

So what am doing is:

```
$(this).parent().next().("a") //doesn't work
```

How can I combine the next() function with a selector like a or select something by its class or id?

I couldn't find anything on jQuery documentation for that.

Comment: $(this).parent().next().find("a") //work!

Comment: Hi, have a look at the posted answers. If it works out for you, click on the `✔` button next to the answer to accept it as a way of telling thanks to answerer. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.

```
$(this).parent().next().find("a") //it work
```

Comment: Don't even need to add find. Just put "a" inside of next

Answer (score 2):

With your current set-up, using this works:

```
$(this).parent().next("a");
```

By the way, your markup is **wrong**. You cannot have a `<a>` as a sibling of `<td>`, which means, either the `<td>` is not inside `<tr>` or `<a>` is inside `<tr>`, which is **wrong**. So I assume your markup is similar to this:

```
<td>
  <span></span>
</td>
<td>
  <!-- -->
</td>
<a></a>
```

So, if you are putting it like this (**valid markup**):

```
<td>
  <span></span>
</td>
<td>
  <!-- -->
</td>
<td>
  <a></a>
</td>
```

You need to use:

```
$(this).parent().next().children("a");
```